# Rewriting query to delete records

Tags: mysql, sql

Can somebody help to rewrite this query to delete records? I having trouble getting the min(a.scancode) in some way or shape in the where clause.

```
select a.location, min(a.scancode) as tobedeleted
from mig_container_location_1 a
where a.location in (select b.location
                    from mig_container_location_1 b
                    where b.LOCATION like 'v%t%l%b%_____%'
                    group by b.location
                    having count(b.location) = 3)
group by a.LOCATION;
```

Below an example of a table. What I would like to do is delete the lowest scancode of each location.

| Scancode | Location |
| --- | --- |
| 120545254 | VB05 T06 B09 |
| 120545255 | VB05 T06 B09 |

Comment: Delete what rows? (A GROUP BY query references groups of rows, not single rows.)

Comment: I am looking to delete the lowest scancode for each location, as shown in the select statement. However I don't have a clue how to rewrite this query into a delete statement.

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: The MySQL version I am using is 5.7

Answer (score 1):

You want to delete the lowest scancode row per location, provided the location matches the pattern and there are exactly 3 rows for that location. Use a tuple of location and scancode to delete the rows in question.

```
delete from mig_container_location_1
where (location, scancode) in 
(
  select location, min(scancode)
  from (select * from mig_container_location_1) t
  where location like 'v%t%l%b%_____%'
  group by location
  having count(*) = 3
);
```

I must select `from (select * from mig_container_location_1) t` instead of merely `from mig_container_location_1` here, because MySQL doesn't allow the table you are deleting from directly in the subquery; we must put it one level deeper.

In case of performance issues, I recommend this index:

```
create index idx on mytable (location, scancode);
```

It may help the inner query to filter the locations and even find their minimum scancode quickly. And it will help the outer query to find the row by location and scancode to delete.

Comment: Yes this seems to be the right solution, I am facing some performance issues since the query seem to be executing anything. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Deletes can take long. This depends of course on how big the table is and how many rows are deleted from it. In an RDBMS the main instrument to get things faster is provding appropriate indexes. I've updated my answer with an index recommendation for the statement.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use GROUP BY in a DELETE statement. If you want to delete every record included in this statement, you can use the same WHERE clause. This would do that, however, it is a bit dangerous to blindly delete so many possible records.

```
DELETE FROM mig_container_location_1 WHERE scancode IN (
select min(a.scancode) as scancode
from mig_container_location_1 a
where a.location in (select b.location
    from mig_container_location_1 b
    where b.LOCATION like 'v%t%l%b%_____%'
    group by b.location
    having count(b.location) = 3)
group by a.LOCATION);
```

I don't have enough data to understand what your second WHERE statement is doing.  It is obviously filtering for specific locations.  This complicates the WHERE statement too much and may have to be done in a STORED PROCEDURE.

However, if you just want to delete the min scancode from every location, you could try this.

```
DELETE FROM mig_container_location_1 WHERE scancode IN (
   SELECT MIN(scancode) AS scancode 
   FROM mig_container_location_1
   GROUP BY location);
```

EDIT:  If your only other criteria is if the same location repeats 3 times, then lets add "HAVING COUNT(location) = 3".  But what if there happens to be 4 or more occurrences? I think you might want to capture anything that is greater then 2.  "HAVING COUNT(location) > 2"

```
DELETE FROM mig_container_location_1 WHERE scancode IN (
   SELECT MIN(scancode) AS scancode
   FROM mig_container_location_1
   GROUP BY location
   HAVING COUNT(location) > 2)
```

Comment: You are very close, however you did not include the min(a.scancode) in this query. This was the most tricky part which I couldn't solve.

Comment: OK, I understand better now.  If I knew your whole table structure I could possibly get a more accurate statement, but you basically just need to add your whole select statement to a DELETE statement.  I will edit the answer to show an example.

Comment: exactly, I don't think the table structure will help solving this problem.

Comment: Just remember that this will delete all records with that scancode.  So if the scancode is not unique, this will be bad.

Comment: I have tested your query, which resulted in the following error: 
 
"You can't specify target table 'mig_container_location_1' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: I edited the answer to include another option that will delete the lowest scancode for every location.  That may be a dangerous DELETE statement.

Comment: You are deleting all rows the scancode of which happens to be the minimum scancode for some location. As far as I understand the request, though, we should only delete the row if the scancode is the minimum scancode for the row's location.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Exactly, I would like to delete the lowest scancode for each location that appears 3 times. The query by ideaztech is only deleting the lowest scancodes after grouping the locations.

Comment: I edited the answer with an alternative that will only delete the lowest scancode that appears 3 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from mig_container_location_1 a
where a.LOCATION like 'v%t%l%b%_____%'
  and a.scancode in (select min(b.lscancode)
                     from mig_container_location_1 b
                     where b.location = a.location
                     group by b.location
                     having count(b.location) = 3)
```